# Icon inside button in HTML

Tags: html

I need to put small icon inside button in HTML (for example I need to have facebook button on my site, inside button first F icon and then "facebook"). How to do that ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```css
.facebook-button {
  background: url('https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-lFFvYHv-Z8w/WAOFS0P5FdI/AAAAAAAAF68/Aiv0D5NkUKIbL3_6G42LZm1iQ6co1tmgACLcB/s320/facebook-16px.png') left center no-repeat;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<input type="button" class="facebook-button" value=" Facebook" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 16):

```
<button><img src="facebook.png" alt=""> Facebook</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following data using the path name for the image

```
 <img src="images/facebook-logo.png"/>
```

Add the width and height attributes if you want to resize the icon

```
 <img src="images/facebook-logo.png" width="75" height="75"/>
```