# Input fields and custom icon

Tags: html

I want the users to be able to update their image straight from the phone and the new HTML5 input fields makes this possible. However the input field is as usual pretty ugly, so I want to make a design where I have a camera icon in the middle of the picture.

[image: Screenshot]

As seen above (beside its not centered) I need to get rid of the old input field, where I can use these:

```
            ::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
                color:    #999;
            }
            :-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
                color:    #999;
            }
            ::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
                color:    #999;
            }
            :-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
                color:    #999;
            }
```

However this does not make the cameraicon clickable. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is same like this question:
[Icon inside button in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101977/icon-inside-button-in-html)

As @Alec explained:

CSS:

```
.facebook-button {
 background: url('facebook-logo.png') left center no-repeat;
 padding-left: 15px;
```

}

HTML:

```
<input type="button" class="facebook-button" value="Facebook" />
```